# Run test for multiple accounts on different providers

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying trying to set up an e2e test suite for cypress. The project I want to test is kind of like vercel. It has multiple git providers where you can login and host your code from that gitprovider.

I am trying to create a simple function I can use that runs the test for all the different providers.

This what I have now for the custom command:

```js
// commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add("loginToProviders", (callback) => {
  // login with github
  cy.loginGithub();
  callback("github");
  cy.clearCookies();

  // login with bitbucket
  cy.loginBitbucket();
  callback();
  cy.clearCookies();

  // login with gitlab
  cy.loginGitlab();
  callback();
  cy.clearCookies();
});
```

and this is how I was imagining the test should look:

```js
// providertest.spec.cy.js
describe("test login for all providers", () => {
  cy.loginToProvider((provider) => {
    it(`test login of ${provider}`, () => {
      cy.visit("/");
      cy.url().should("be.equal", `${Cypress.config("baseUrl")}/`);
    });
  });
});
```

the problem I am running into is that you cant run cy commands outside a test. I am struggling to find documentation for these kinds of situations, does anyone know where I can find more info which kind of describes my case. Or any pointers of how I should refactor the code. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

**You can't run cy commands outside a test** - correct, so one answer is change the custom command to a function, and move the `it()` block inside the function.

```js
function testEachProvider(callback) {

  // login with github
  it('test login of github', () => {
    cy.loginGithub();
    callback("github");
    cy.clearCookies();
  })

  // login with bitbucket
  it('test login of bitbucket', () => {
    cy.loginBitbucket();
    callback("bitbucket");
    cy.clearCookies();
  })

  // login with gitlab
  it('test login of gitlab', () => {
    cy.loginGitlab();
    callback("gitlab");
    cy.clearCookies();
  })
})

describe("test login for all providers", () => {
  testEachProvider((provider) => {
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.url().should("be.equal", `${Cypress.config("baseUrl")}/`);
  });
})
```

---

Another structure is a simple loop, and parameterize the login command name. using the pattern described here [Dynamic Tests From Cypress Fixture](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/dynamic-tests-from-fixture/)

Since commands are properties of `cy`, you should be able to extract the correct login command by name and invoke it with `()`.

```js
const providers = ['github', 'bitbucket', 'gitlab']

providers.forEach(provider => {

  it(`tests ${provider}`, () => {

    cy.clearCookies()  

    const capFirstProvider = provider.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + provider.slice(1)
    const loginCommand = `login${capFirstProvider}`
    cy[loginCommand]()                              // invoke login command

    cy.visit("/");
    cy.url().should("be.equal", `${Cypress.config("baseUrl")}/`)

  })
})
```

Note, if you use default `testIsolation` setting of `true`, then `cy.clearCookies()` is not required - Cypress does that for you plus a bunch of other cleardown steps.

---

You can generalize the dynamic data using an array of objects.

```js
const providers = [
 { name: 'github', loginCommand: 'loginGithub' },
 { name: 'bitbucket', loginCommand: 'loginBitbucket' }, 
 { name: 'gitlab', loginCommand: 'loginGitlab' }
]

providers.forEach(provider => {

  it(`tests ${provider.name}`, () => {

    cy[provider.loginCommand]()      // invoke login command

    cy.visit("/");
    cy.url().should("be.equal", `${Cypress.config("baseUrl")}/`)

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think re-structuring and how you think about your tests could be valuable here. Instead of having them all run inside of a custom command, why not have the custom command take in a parameter and act accordingly.

```js
// Custom command that only runs the login command depending on provider
Cypress.Commands.add('loginToProvider', (provider) => {
  if (provider === 'Github') {
    return cy.loginGithub();
  } else if (provider === 'Bitbucket') {
    return cy.loginBitbucket();
  } else if (provider === 'Gitlab') {
    return cy.loginGitlab();
  } else {
    return cy.wrap(null); // arbitrary else statement
  }
});

// Tests.js

// define potential providers
const providers = ['Github', 'Bitbucket', 'Gitlab']
describe('Provider Tests', () => {
  // Use Cypress Lodash to iterate through providers array
  Cypress._.times(providers.length, (index) => {
    const provider = providers[index];

    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.clearCookies(); // unsure if necessary, but recommended to clear before each test runs
    });

    it(`Tests Login for Provider: ${provider}`, () => {
      cy.loginToProvider(provider);
      cy.visit('/');
      cy.url().should('be.equal', `${Cypress.config('baseUrl')}/`);
    })
  })
});
```